# how to combine two angular expressions in ng-src directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to dynamically generate image url in ng-reapeat like this

```
<img  ng-src="{{baseurl}}+{{category.imageurl}}">
```

the above code is not working. Please help me how can I do it.

Comment: hey i am facing same problem you will get any solution for this ... if yes then please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

If the `+` is out of the mustaches, it's not interpretedt at all and ends up being in the attribute value. You just need

```
{{baseurl}}{{category.imageurl}}
```

or, better,

```
{{baseurl + category.imageurl}}
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not working. only baseurl is appearing in HTM L  <img id="category" ng-src="http://kheapfiles.blob.core.windows.net/images/" alt="Automotive" src="http://kheapfiles.blob.core.windows.net/images/">

Comment: Then it means that `category.imageurl` is blank, or null, or undefined. What is displayed on the page if you add `{{ category }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of AngularJS you are using, this is expected.

Check this out:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-